# How to center items in <TablePagination> component Material Table UI React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pagination

I've tried everything including making a css class which will affect the color, but it won't do anything with the vertical alignment which looks like this:[image]

Any ideas?

```css
  .paginator {
    background-color: #99977b;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    align-items: center;
```

```html
                    <TablePagination className="paginator"
                        rowsPerPageOptions={process.env.REACT_APP_ROWS_PER_PAGE_OPTIONS.split(',').map(Number)}
                        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                        page={page}
                        count={rows.length}
                        component="div"
                        onPageChange={handlePageChange}
                        onRowsPerPageChange={handleRowsPerPageChange}
                    >

                    </TablePagination>
```

Comment: What is your expected behaviour exactly, ? MUI defaultly set this to a center - see this: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-mirzakhani-8kjrj8   Also, Share your code to codesandbox, so we can debug the issue.

Comment: I want everything to line up. See how the text is aligned to to the top and the dropdowns/arrow keys are centered vertically? I want them all centered vertically

Comment: @Pat did you solve this issue? if yes, how?